# How can I store the mongodb connection instance of multiple db in cache for faster connectivity?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, multi-tenant, saas

I'm creating a SaaS application using multi-tenant architecture and MongoDB as database. How can I store the connection instance of multiple databases in the cache so that I can speed up the database calling process?

When the server starts all the databases of each tenant are connected by mongoose.createConnection and are stored inside a local variable. But whenever a new tenant is created the connection instance of that database doesn't get added to that local variable.

I've tried using redis for this but since the mongodb connection instance is not in proper JSON format it cannot be stored inside the redis.